# What is this type of popover ad called?

Tags: wordpress

I hate linking to a site to describe this.  But on this page after I believe 10 seconds or so, an ad will popup for iPage.

webhostingreviewboards.com/wordpress-plugins/10-free-wordpress-plugins-for-landing-pages-to-capture-leads/

What is that type of popup / popover ad called?  I am trying to find a plugin for that to use on a wordpress site for a client of mine, but it's hard to search for when you don't have a specific name for that type of object.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a 'Modal' or some call it a 'Lightbox'. But search for 'wordpress timed modal plugin' and you should get the results that you need.